# Can I automatically add a guest user (guest-session) to a user group? How can I do it)

Tags: permissions, users, user-management, guest-session, groups

I need guest users to be in a specific user group. I probably could create a new guest-account and add it to the group. But I'd rather like to use the existing guest-session-option integrated in Ubuntu (16.04). Is there any way to do it? I only found ways to automaticaly launch scripts/programs or costumize the startup-dialog.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. To make the guest users belong to `mygroup`, create `/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh` and add the line:

```
adduser $USER mygroup
```