# guest-session and printer pause

Tags: permissions, printing, guest-session

This may be a bug/feature or my misconfiguration...

Logged in Ubuntu as a guest user
(customized https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession)

When user clicks or somehow makes print(local USB printer or network)
 to pause the same user can not activate unpause(continue print) back.
Logout an login as guest makes no difference printer stays paused.

Reactivation/unpause(continue print) is only possible if you logout an login as different user that is not guest.

What permissions I have to change, so the guest can unpause paused printer?

Answer (score 0):

Found a dirty solution for this bug/feature. It works ok, for quite some time, but it's dangerous ! Using this method user can unpause but also delete/add.... printer!

Still searching for safer solution.

Key was this answer: [Can I automatically add a guest user (guest-session) to a user group? How can I do it)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844182/can-i-automatically-add-a-guest-user-guest-session-to-a-user-group-how-can-i)

```
sudo nano /etc/guest-session/prefs.sh
```

If you haven’t created this file before, then its an empty file. Add this line:

```
adduser $USER lpadmin
```